# moving vertices along view axis between camera and vertex position

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, photogrammetry

I do want to model something that i a have photographed in 2 different perspectives.

So after modeling it looking through one camera, i do want to slide the vertices back and forth along the vector describing the direction between camera origin and vertex position (and not the view axis, because that would always be the same direction for every pixel of the image)

It's like creating a vertex while viewing from a fixed position/rotation, than making an edge to the viewing origin and vertex sliding the first vertex without clamp.

Answer (score 1):

Select the camera along whose view you wish to move verts.  Snap cursor to selection.  Enter edit on the mesh.  Change pivot point to cursor.  Scale the vertices you wish to move.  Their position in the view of that camera will not change-- they slide along the line containing the pivot point and their position.

Answer (score 0):

Create a plane and delete all but one vertex then move the origin of the plane to this vertex. Copy the camera coordinates to this vertex object so they are in the same position. On your target object extrude a vertex and snap it to the camera vertex. Now you have an edge between the camera and target vertex that you can subdivide and vertex slide using G-G.

Comment: Thank you for helping out! I think what you describe is what i mentioned in the last sentence. I was hoping there would be another faster way to accomplish that. Like positioning the 3DCursor on the new Vertex and than using that as an transformation orientation axes in the dropdown... if i could than preselect that option, i would only ever need to move the Cursor to the new vertex and move it along that y axis.